# Problems with my invincibility frames feature

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working on a game as a project and I've gotten round to introducing invincibility frames when the player takes a heart of damage. In this case I want it so that the player model flashes roughly once every 0.1 seconds and to have the invincibility last for 2 seconds.

I've written this code and I can't figure out why it isn't working. By the way using this code when the player takes damage they cannot take damage afterwards so something is really messed up (it isn't just the visual invincibility being an issue).
(Thank you)

```cs
private void loseHealth()
{

    if (invinTimerCounter == 0)
    {
        curHealth -= 1;
        invinTimerCounter = invinTimer;
        invincibilityBlink();
    }
}

private void invincibilityBlink()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Invoke("spriteDisable", 1);
        Invoke("spriteEnable", 1);
    }
}

private void spriteEnable()
{
    this.spriteRenderer.enabled = true;
}

private void spriteDisable()
{
    this.spriteRenderer.enabled = false;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (invinTimerCounter < 0)
    {
        invinTimerCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the check in `Update()` be `if (invinTimerCounter > 0)`?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to jmalenfant's comment, I'd like to rewrite your `invincibilityBlink()` method to use a [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html):

```
private IEnumerator invincibilityBlink()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        spriteDisable();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        spriteEnable();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    }
    invincible = false;
}
```

Then, here:

```
if (!invincible)
{
    curHealth -= 1;
    invincible = true;
    StartCoroutine(invincibilityBlink());
}
```

Oh, and we'll change that messy float to a boolean and let the coroutine handle it too, so if you decide to change the invincibility time, you only need to change things in one place.

Comment: I would even move the `invincible` on top of the Coroutine so it gets set `true` when the routine starts and `false` when it is done. If you really need dedicated methods for one line code is questionable ;)

Comment: @derHugo Oh, the `spriteDisable()` and `spriteEnable()` functions (as written) are dumb and pointless, but you never know when you might want to make those be more complicated. But yeah, I agree in general. I didn't inline those two methods because that wasn't the point of what I was trying to show.

Comment: I know ;) the last part was more addressed to OP ;)